# How can I use environment variables if I use vuejs with CDN?

Tags: vue.js, npm, dotenv

I was using Vuejs CDN to develop my app. Now, I want to separate dev and prod since the API endpoints are separated. I don't want to expose my dev API endpoint. How can I do it with the simplest way?

I tried to use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv). Put the DEBUG variable in .env.

```
var debug = process.env.DEBUG;
console.log(debug);

Vue.directive('focus', {
    inserted: function (el) {
        el.focus()
    }
})

var vm =  new Vue({...
```

My .env file

```
DEBUG=true
```

I can read the debug variable. However, it gives an error of "Vue is not defined" since I didn't install Vue with npm. Or I must install Vue with npm?

Comment: Please post full code or a live in codesandbox

Comment: OK, I've updated with more context now

Comment: *"I don't want to expose my dev API endpoint"* — What does that mean exactly? If you don't want the visitor of the dev website to be able to see what URL Vue makes requests to, that's by definition impossible. The browser has to make the request, and the user can inspect any and all requests the browser makes.

Comment: if (dev env)
        url = 'dev endpoint';
    else // dev
        url = 'prod endpoint';


I was thinking to use something similar to separate dev and prod. If I check with hostname in js, it will expose the api when someone views source. 

I was using this way to separate dev & prod in my previous django app. When there is a server-side app, I can print the if with django

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org), facilities for this are already built in in the form of [.env files](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables). You'd create `.env.dev` and `.env.production` files (and probably a `.env.local` for local development), containing:

```
VUE_APP_ENDPOINT=https://...
```

Which in your Javascript files you can access as:

```
const endpoint = process.env.VUE_APP_ENDPOINT;
```

Then you create different builds for your two different environments:

```
vue-cli-service build --mode dev  # or --mode production
```

The variables will be baked into the build, so your two different builds only contain their respective endpoints.